# How to add custom attribute to bootstrap select2 li items?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I am using bootstrap select2 to provide a searchable dropdown. The data is filled dynamically. I would like to have a custom attribute on all li elements:

```
 $('#myselect').select2({
      data: myDataArray
 });
```

This works perfectly and renders the following html:

```
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-myselect-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">item1</li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">item2</li>
     <!-- etc, total of 77 items listed --> 
</ul>
```

On all the list elements I would like have an attribute.
So I figured out, I have to catch the 'select2:open' event when the elements are already rendered, then apply the attribute say with jquery:

```
 $("#myselect").on("select2:open", function () {
     console.log('open');
     var liElements = $('#select2-myselect-results li');
     console.log(liElements.length);
     liElements.attr('data-mydata', 'mydataa');
 });
```

The event fires correctly. The console shows for first open:

> ```
> open
> 1
> ```

The console shows for second open, it also seems the jquery selector is working:
(but why only just 2 time...?, anyway)

> ```
> open
> 77
> ```

**The main problem that the `li` elements are not having the `data-mydata` attribute in either case which is my goal.**
The side question is why the first open has only one element (even zero would have more sense...)

*No error messages on the console*

Answer (score 0):

I find it out: Must wait for DOM events to be completed. I think the idea is useful for similar cases. Use the setTimeout trick (with 0) to execute your code in the next iterations of the browser's message loop.

In practice:

```
$("#myselect").on("select2:open", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var liElements = $('#select2-myselect-results li');
        console.log(liElements.length);
        liElements.attr('data-mydata', 'mydataa');
    }, 0);
});
```

The event fires correctly. The console shows for first open:

> ```
> open
> 76
> ```

**...and the attribute is there.**

PS: This explains the side question: why was 1 first time and 77 second time?
Because that was the state before the DOM changes. The second time 77 was the leftover from the 1st opening, what probably was deleted to create the new ones.

So we wait, and apply the attribute on the create new ones...